# "Corrupted" color fill of the world map - using geom_map

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, spatial

I want to visualize some data on world map using ggplot, maps and mapdata

The link to the .xls file is [here](https://upload.cat/1a2689d08ae87510)*

Let's see the code:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(mapproj)

mapka <- read_xls(path="Yourpath/mapy2.xls")

m <-map_data("world")
choro <-merge(m, mapka, by="region", all.x=TRUE)
for (i in 1:nrow(choro)) {
  if (is.na(choro$a[i]==TRUE)){choro$a[i]<-0}
  if (is.na(choro$b[i]==TRUE)){choro$b[i]<-0}}

ggplot()+
  geom_map(data=choro, map=choro, aes(long,lat, map_id=region, fill=a)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels=NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=NULL)
```

However when I execute the code I got this strange image:
[image]

What's wrong? Previously I did not have such a problem. It looks terrible.

*Anyone knows better free .xls/.xlsx repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to give us something as code that replicates the problem you are having. I was able to replicate your code without using the link you provided. My suggestion would be to use `left_join()` instead of `merge()` and `replace_na()` instead of the for loop.

```r
library(maps)
library(tidyverse)
library(mapdata)
library(ggthemes)
library(mapproj)

m <- 
  map_data("world") 

mapka <-
  m %>% 
  distinct(region) %>% 
  slice(1:100) %>% 
  mutate(a = c(1:100)*40)

# replicates your issue
choro <- merge(m, mapka, by = "region", all.x = TRUE)

for (i in 1:nrow(choro)) {
  if (is.na(choro$a[i]) == TRUE) {
    choro$a[i] <- 0
  }
}  

ggplot() +
  geom_map(
    data = choro, map = choro, 
    aes(long, lat, map_id = region, fill = a)
  )

# using left_join and replace_na
choro <-
  m %>% 
  left_join(mapka) %>% 
  mutate(a = replace_na(a, 0))

ggplot() +
  geom_map(
    data = choro, map = choro, 
    aes(long, lat, map_id = region, fill = a)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the complex advice, I admit that I need to learn to optimize my R code. Let me ask additional ask. How to set color brewer with for a=0 (gray) and a>0 blue palette?

Comment: You can skip the `na_replace()` step and the `NA` values will be grey by default. For color brewer, you can use this code `+ scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1, na.value = "grey70")`. As you can see, you can adjust the color of the `NA` values here. For more on optimizing code, I would recommend Hadley Wickham's R for Data Science book (also free online).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `left_join` instead of merge?
Without having the mapka data it is not possible to debug your code.